# Buscar ID numa coluna de IDs separados por delimitador no MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Eu uso uma tabela chamada `chat` e dentro dela tem toda uma estrutura para meu script de bate-papo e estou tentando criar chat em grupos, até aí tudo bem. Entretanto, dentro da tabela `chat` tem uma coluna chamada `participantes` onde eu insiro os participantes do grupo dessa forma:

```
01,02,03,04,05,6,0,2,522....
```

Onde cada numeral até a virgula corresponde ao ID do usuario, ou seja 01 -> Eu 02-> você ou qualquer outro e assim vai...

A questão é, como eu busco todos os resultados que contenham meu `id` na coluna `participantes`? Como ler cada número virgula por virgula até achar o meu em toda a tabela? Existe uma forma padrão do MySQL pra isso?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Apenas com SELECT

Como lembrado pelo @bfavaretto, o MySQL tem uma função específica para sua necessidade:

```
SELECT * FROM chat WHERE FIND_IN_SET( '09', participantes );
```

a solução mais geral para diversos dialetos SQL é você localizar desta maneira:

```
SELECT * FROM chat WHERE CONCAT( ",", participantes, "," ) LIKE '%,09,%';
```

porém, se tiver muitos dados a performance *não vai ser das mais surpreendentes* <sup>1</sup>. Claro que no PHP você vai colocar uma variável no lugar do `09` do exemplo (com cuidado para evitar SQL Injection).

Lembre-se de acertar seus ítens para que fiquem de maneira consistente, pois no seu exemplo tem coisas com um, dois e três dígitos, e algumas com zero anterior e outras não, o que é sinal de algo *levemente estranho* <sup>2</sup> se no caso real estiver realmente dessa forma.

### Melhor seria...

...usar uma tabela auxiliar relacionando os participantes às salas, assim você teria algo nesse modelo:

```
 sala | participante
------+---------------
    1 |  12     
    1 |   7     
    1 | 342     
    1 |   1
    2 |  12
    2 |  28
    3 |   1
...
```

Assim bastaria dar uma estudada em como fazer um **[JOIN](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6448/70)** para localizar os dados. Você além de organizar melhor seus dados, vai poder se beneficiar do uso de índices para deixar mais eficiente seu `SELECT`, e provavelmente vai poder aproveitar esta tabela para outras partes do seu sistema, que hoje dependem do campo separado por vírgulas.

<sub>1. horrível, no caso do `like`, um pouco melhor no `find_in_set`</sub>

<sub>2. zica</sub>

Comment: dei +1 pela resposta, dava +10 pelo ponto 1 :)

Comment: Normalize a tabela. Não complique coisas simples.

Comment: @Motta a tabela não é minha. Sugiro que você recomende ao OP. Eu só tou respondendo ao que foi perguntado, pra não complicar o que é simples (e com três alternativas que funcionam). De qualquer forma, acho que você pode cancelar a exclusão da sua resposta, editá-la com mais detalhes e explicar pro OP como normalizar, e os motivos. Com certeza se for uma boa resposta, terá meu +1 (e de outros usuários).

Comment: @Bacco , só acho que ficar procurando solução sem atacar o problema real é perda de tempo, evidente que tem solução via SQL como  concat , uso de funções de string etc, mas isto não resolve o problema pois ele vai aparecer em outro ponto da aplicação. Sigo com minha modesta opinião, a solução é normalizar a tabela.

Comment: @Motta Não estou discordando, só acho que na minha resposta não é o lugar apropriado pra você questionar isso. Eu realmente acho que se você postar uma resposta mais completa, explicando ao OP como normalizar a tabela e explicando suas vantagens, você estará defendendo seu posicionamento da maneira mais correta e eficaz. Não é questão de estar certo ou errado, e sim de usar o site de maneira mais produtiva para você e para os futuros leitores. Sua opinião é bem-vinda, mas há meios mais adequados para você fazer ela valer.